# SQL (or python) select value once from similar rows

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I have data in an Oracle table from which I need to select certain rows based on the number of unique values that repeat due to grouping.  My data looks like this.

```
| LINE | BUCKET | TERM | COURSE     |
|------|--------|------|------------|
| 1001 | 1      | FA18 | COURSE 101 |
| 1001 | 1      | SP19 | COURSE 102 |
| 1001 | 1      | SP19 | COURSE 103 |
| 1001 | 1      | FA19 | COURSE 104 |
| 1001 | 2      | FA18 | COURSE 101 |
| 1001 | 2      | SP19 | COURSE 102 |
| 1001 | 2      | SP19 | COURSE 103 |
| 1001 | 2      | FA19 | COURSE 104 |
| 2001 | 1      | FA18 | COURSE 201 |
| 2001 | 1      | SP19 | COURSE 202 |
| 2001 | 1      | FA20 | COURSE 203 |
| 2001 | 2      | FA18 | COURSE 201 |
| 2001 | 2      | SP19 | COURSE 202 |
| 2001 | 2      | FA20 | COURSE 203 |
| 2001 | 3      | FA18 | COURSE 201 |
| 2001 | 3      | SP19 | COURSE 202 |
| 2001 | 3      | FA20 | COURSE 203 |
```

There are two lines in the data.  The first line (1001) has 2 different buckets and 4 distinct courses.  The second line (2001) has 3 different buckets and 3 distinct courses.  I need to
select only 1 row for each course in a line and as many buckets as possible.  The math is simple:

- Line 1001: 4 (courses) / 2 (buckets) = 2 courses for each bucket
- Line 2001: 3 (courses) / 3 (buckets) = 1 course for each bucket

How do I select a course once per line across multiple buckets to look like this?

```
| LINE | BUCKET | TERM | COURSE     |
|------|--------|------|------------|
| 1001 | 1      | FA18 | COURSE 101 |
| 1001 | 1      | SP19 | COURSE 102 |
| 1001 | 2      | SP19 | COURSE 103 |
| 1001 | 2      | FA19 | COURSE 104 |
| 2001 | 1      | FA18 | COURSE 201 |
| 2001 | 2      | SP19 | COURSE 202 |
| 2001 | 3      | FA20 | COURSE 203 |
```

The solution could be either SQL or python.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is `row_number()`.  If you want just a random sampling of buckets:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by line, course order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you actually want to round-robin on the buckets (to guarantee that the maximum number is chosen), then random is not sufficient:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by line, course order by seqnum_bucket, dbms_random.random) as seqnum
      from (select t.*
                   row_number() over (partition by line, course, bucket order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum_bucket
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @JElwood . . . You can replace `random` with any column you like.  Your problem made it sound like you wanted a random sample.

Answer (score 0):

If your buckets always start from 1 and increment=1, you can use very simple `mod(row_number, max(bucket))`:

```sql
select
   line, term, course
  ,1+mod(-1+row_number()over(partition by line order by course),max(bucket)) bucket_n
from t 
group by line, term, course
order by line,course;
```

Full example with sample data:

```sql
with t(LINE ,BUCKET ,TERM ,COURSE) as (
   select 1001, 1, 'FA18', 'COURSE 101' from dual union all
   select 1001, 1, 'SP19', 'COURSE 102' from dual union all
   select 1001, 1, 'SP19', 'COURSE 103' from dual union all
   select 1001, 1, 'FA19', 'COURSE 104' from dual union all
   select 1001, 2, 'FA18', 'COURSE 101' from dual union all
   select 1001, 2, 'SP19', 'COURSE 102' from dual union all
   select 1001, 2, 'SP19', 'COURSE 103' from dual union all
   select 1001, 2, 'FA19', 'COURSE 104' from dual union all
   select 2001, 1, 'FA18', 'COURSE 201' from dual union all
   select 2001, 1, 'SP19', 'COURSE 202' from dual union all
   select 2001, 1, 'FA20', 'COURSE 203' from dual union all
   select 2001, 2, 'FA18', 'COURSE 201' from dual union all
   select 2001, 2, 'SP19', 'COURSE 202' from dual union all
   select 2001, 2, 'FA20', 'COURSE 203' from dual union all
   select 2001, 3, 'FA18', 'COURSE 201' from dual union all
   select 2001, 3, 'SP19', 'COURSE 202' from dual union all
   select 2001, 3, 'FA20', 'COURSE 203' from dual
)
select
   line, term, course
  ,1+mod(-1+row_number()over(partition by line order by course),max(bucket)) bucket_n
from t 
group by line, term, course
order by line,course;
```

Results:

```
LINE    TERM    COURSE      BUCKET_N
------- ------- ----------- --------
1001    FA18    COURSE 101  1
1001    SP19    COURSE 102  2
1001    SP19    COURSE 103  1
1001    FA19    COURSE 104  2
2001    FA18    COURSE 201  1
2001    SP19    COURSE 202  2
2001    FA20    COURSE 203  3
```

Another interesting variant is to aggregate buckets and extract the value by position `mod(rownumber, count(buckets))` - in opposite to previous solution, it works for any buckets:

```sql
select
   line, term, course
  ,xmlcast(
     xmlelement(
        "buckets",  
        xmlagg(xmlelement("bucket", bucket))
     ).extract('/buckets/*['||
      (1+mod(-1+row_number()over(partition by line order by course),count(bucket)))
     ||']')
    as int) bucket_n_2
from t 
group by line, term, course
order by line,course;
```

Full test case:

```sql
with t(LINE ,BUCKET ,TERM ,COURSE) as (
   select 1001, 1, 'FA18', 'COURSE 101' from dual union all
   select 1001, 1, 'SP19', 'COURSE 102' from dual union all
   select 1001, 1, 'SP19', 'COURSE 103' from dual union all
   select 1001, 1, 'FA19', 'COURSE 104' from dual union all
   select 1001, 2, 'FA18', 'COURSE 101' from dual union all
   select 1001, 2, 'SP19', 'COURSE 102' from dual union all
   select 1001, 2, 'SP19', 'COURSE 103' from dual union all
   select 1001, 2, 'FA19', 'COURSE 104' from dual union all
   select 2001, 1, 'FA18', 'COURSE 201' from dual union all
   select 2001, 1, 'SP19', 'COURSE 202' from dual union all
   select 2001, 1, 'FA20', 'COURSE 203' from dual union all
   select 2001, 2, 'FA18', 'COURSE 201' from dual union all
   select 2001, 2, 'SP19', 'COURSE 202' from dual union all
   select 2001, 2, 'FA20', 'COURSE 203' from dual union all
   select 2001, 3, 'FA18', 'COURSE 201' from dual union all
   select 2001, 3, 'SP19', 'COURSE 202' from dual union all
   select 2001, 3, 'FA20', 'COURSE 203' from dual
)
select
   line, term, course
  ,1+mod(-1+row_number()over(partition by line order by course),max(bucket)) bucket_n
  ,xmlcast(
     xmlelement(
        "buckets",  
        xmlagg(xmlelement("bucket", bucket))
     ).extract('/buckets/*['||
      (1+mod(-1+row_number()over(partition by line order by course),count(bucket)))
     ||']')
    as int) bucket_n_2
from t 
group by line, term, course
order by line,course;
```

- `xmlagg(xmlelement("bucket", bucket))` aggregates all buckets numbers.
- `extract('/buckets/*[N])` - extracts N's buckets from aggregated value
- `(1+mod(-1+row_number()over(partition by line order by course),count(bucket)))` - calculates Nth buckets

Results : BUCKET_N - previous, BUCKET_N_2 - new variant:

```
LINE    TERM    COURSE      BUCKET_N    BUCKET_N_2
1001    FA18    COURSE 101          1           1
1001    SP19    COURSE 102          2           2
1001    SP19    COURSE 103          1           1
1001    FA19    COURSE 104          2           2
2001    FA18    COURSE 201          1           1
2001    SP19    COURSE 202          2           3
2001    FA20    COURSE 203          3           2
```